# Visual Studio c# Telerik Reporting

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, telerik, telerik-reporting

I've just downloaded Telerik and can't find much help on the internet.  I want to be able to generate a flashy report, and Telerik looks like the way to go.  That being said, I don't want to use all the wizards and junk to build my report. Is there not some kind of "report_load" function that I can use when the report loads. I need to be able to have the connection string configurable, and I have the user inputting some values that generates the report.

Here is the code that generates the report:

```
private void GenerateReport()
    {
        DBaseConn.Open();
        SqlCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT Gate, Weight, Date_Created FROM Backrib_Manifest " +
                                    "WHERE Date_Created >= '" + fromddate + "'" + 
                                    "AND Date_Created <= '" + todate + "'", DBaseConn);
        DataReader = SqlCommand.ExecuteReader();

        while (DataReader.Read())
        {
            switch (Convert.ToInt32(DataReader["Gate"]))
            {
                case 1:
                    gatecount[0]++;
                    gate1weight += double.Parse(DataReader["Weight"].ToString());
                    break;
                case 2:
                    gatecount[1]++;
                    gate2weight += double.Parse(DataReader["Weight"].ToString());
                    break;
                case 3:
                    gatecount[2]++;
                    gate3weight += double.Parse(DataReader["Weight"].ToString());
                    break;
                case 4:
                    gatecount[3]++;
                    gate4weight += double.Parse(DataReader["Weight"].ToString());
                    break;
                case 5:
                    gatecount[4]++;
                    gate5weight += double.Parse(DataReader["Weight"].ToString());
                    break;
                case 6:
                    gatecount[5]++;
                    gate6weight += double.Parse(DataReader["Weight"].ToString());
                    break;
                case 7:
                    gatecount[6]++;
                    gate7weight += double.Parse(DataReader["Weight"].ToString());
                    break;
                case 8:
                    gatecount[7]++;
                    gate8weight += double.Parse(DataReader["Weight"].ToString());
                    break;
                case 0:
                    gatecount[8]++;
                    gate0weight += double.Parse(DataReader["Weight"].ToString());
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
        DBaseConn.Close();

        int totalcount = gatecount[0] + gatecount[1] + gatecount[2] + gatecount[3] + gatecount[4] +
                         gatecount[5] + gatecount[6] + gatecount[7] + gatecount[8];

        lblCount1.Text = gatecount[0].ToString();
        lblCount2.Text = gatecount[1].ToString();
        lblCount3.Text = gatecount[2].ToString();
        lblCount4.Text = gatecount[3].ToString();
        lblCount5.Text = gatecount[4].ToString();
        lblCount6.Text = gatecount[5].ToString();
        lblCount7.Text = gatecount[6].ToString();
        lblCount8.Text = gatecount[7].ToString();
        //lblCount0.Text = gatecount[8].ToString();
        if (totalcount != 0)
        {
            lblPct1.Text = (gatecount[0] / totalcount).ToString("P2");
            lblPct2.Text = (gatecount[1] / totalcount).ToString("P2");
            lblPct3.Text = (gatecount[2] / totalcount).ToString("P2");
            lblPct4.Text = (gatecount[3] / totalcount).ToString("P2");
            lblPct5.Text = (gatecount[4] / totalcount).ToString("P2");
            lblPct6.Text = (gatecount[5] / totalcount).ToString("P2");
            lblPct7.Text = (gatecount[6] / totalcount).ToString("P2");
            lblPct8.Text = (gatecount[7] / totalcount).ToString("P2");
            //lblPct0.Text = (gatecount[8] / totalcount).ToString("P2");
        }

        lblWeight1.Text = (gate1weight / gatecount[0]).ToString();
        lblWeight2.Text = (gate2weight / gatecount[1]).ToString();
        lblWeight3.Text = (gate3weight / gatecount[2]).ToString();
        lblWeight4.Text = (gate4weight / gatecount[3]).ToString();
        lblWeight5.Text = (gate5weight / gatecount[4]).ToString();
        lblWeight6.Text = (gate6weight / gatecount[5]).ToString();
        lblWeight7.Text = (gate7weight / gatecount[6]).ToString();
        lblWeight8.Text = (gate8weight / gatecount[7]).ToString();
        //lblWeight0.Text = (gate0weight / gatecount[8]).ToString();
    }
```

Is there a way to do this in the report itself?  Of course, I would actually be putting the values in defined places on the report.

Comment: Which Telerik product are you talking about? WinForms, WPF, Silverlight, ASP.Net?

Comment: I have Telerik Winforms, but I'm talking about using Telerik Reporting

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is create a property (or properties) for your report class and set values such as tables, charts, and other elements you are binding to (or otherwise setting values for) in the NeedDataSource (which is the "report_load" you are asking about) event handler. There you can simply bind or set values on the report using those internal property values. This way the connectionstring is irrelevent to your report class, you just set properties (think DataSource for example) and leave the report class to the responsibility of setting its control values internally.

Note: there are 2 classes associated with a Telerik report. The designer partial class which has all of the report controls, etc, and the report class (your custom subclass) itself. The latter is where the NeedDataSource would go.